# how to acess the phonegap database in different pages?

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

i've created a database using database and display in a listview,but i want to use the same 
database in another two pages,so how can i access the same database in many pages??
please go through my code..

```
 var db = window.openDatabase("Mydatabase", "1.0", "Just a My DB", 200000); //will create database Mydatabase or open it
    function onDeviceReady(){
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALLWORDS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Word TEXT NOT NULL, Type_Of_Word TEXT NOT NULL)');

    }
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("error in database : "+err);
    }

    function successCB() {
        alert("successs!");
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }

    function queryDB(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ALLWORDS',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
```

Comment: what is the problem, why not use the same method: `window.openDatabase("Mydatabase", "1.0", "Just a My DB", 200000);`

Comment: it is just for opening the db right?so u want me to copy this in every page and call queryDB() function

Comment: yes, once the DB already exists, it will just return the exisitng DB connection.

Comment: thats what i want to know,how to reuse that db in another page??

Answer (score 1):

The important line is:

```
 var db = window.openDatabase("Mydatabase", "1.0", "Just a My DB", 200000);
```

If the DB doesn't exist it will create it, if it does, it will return a connection to that DB.

So you can put this line in a separate js file, lets call it global.js, and then just include it in every page you need it, all the scripts that are included after that will know that variable, so for example:

**global.js**

```
...
var db = window.openDatabase("Mydatabase", "1.0", "Just a My DB", 200000); //should be defined in the script itself, not inside of a function.
...
```

**script.js**

```
//in the HTML this is included after the global.js so it knows the db variable
function onDeviceReady(){
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
//global should always come first
<script src="global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That way, you only need to define it once. Of course, in the global you should put every other function/variable that is going to be used by many files.

Comment: thanks for ur help..but still im not able to sort out,do i need to include script tags in global.js r script.js files??

Comment: If you look carefully, the title above the included script tag says **HTML**, the same way you include css files in HTML.

Comment: i meant to say should i add script tags in global.js file not in HTML file,or is it enough to copy the line of code

Comment: script tags are just for HTML, js files should only contain the code between the tags, not the tags themselves.